# clicking on tab moves on to next fieldset

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, tabindex

I have a form containing 13 `fieldsets` , each containing non uniform number of fields. I want to use tab to navigate between the fields and in the end it will move on to the next `fieldset`.

I have written one javascript in which i have

```
$('#formElem > fieldset').each(function(){
    var $fieldset = $(this);
        $fieldset.children(':last').find(':input').keydown(function(e){
            if (e.which == 9){
                $('#navigation li:nth-child(' + (parseInt(current)+1) + ') a').click();
                /* force the blur for validation */
                $(this).blur();
            e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
});
```

In my form when my page loads, when i click on tab button it moves on to the next page without traversing my fields in the current `fieldset`, but on the next `fieldset` clicking on tab makes makes my cursor to move to few fields then again without completing my fields it moves on to next `fieldset`.

I am giving details of my first fieldset in my form

```
<form id="formElem" name="formElem" action="report_form_submit.jsp" method="post">
<fieldset class="step">

                            <legend>General Information </legend>
                            <table>
                            <tr><td>
                            <p>
                                <label for="centers" >Name of the Center</label>
                                <%
                                if(user_gr.equals("MA") || user_gr.equals("Ad")){
                                    %>
                                    <select name="centers" id="centers" >
                                <option value="">Select Center</option>

                                <!-- Populate Combobox from Database -->

                               <%
                                while(rsCenters.next()){
                                %>

                                <option value="<%= rsCenters.getInt("id") %>"><%= rsCenters.getString("c_name") %></option>
                                <%
                                }
                               // rsCenters.beforeFirst();
                                %>
                                <!-- Populate Combobox from Database -->

                                </select>
                                    <%
                                }
                                else{
                                    //System.out.println("...SQL CENTER :::"+sqlCenter);
                                    while(rsCenters.next()){
                                        center_name=rsCenters.getString("c_code");
                                    %>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="centers" id="centers" value="<%= rsCenters.getInt("id") %>" />
                                    <input type="text" name="" id="" value="<%= rsCenters.getString("c_name") %>" disabled/>
                                    <%
                                    }
                                }
                                %>

                                <!-- <input id="username" name="username" /> -->
                             <%
}
catch(Exception ex){

System.out.println(ex);
}
%>    
                            </p>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <p>
                                <label for="dt_enrolment">Date of enrolment</label>
                                <input tabindex="1" id="dt_enrolment" name="dt_enrolment" type="text" onclick="gen_dt()" />

                            </p>

                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <p>
                                <label for="srl_no">Serial No</label>
                                 <% if(!rsserial_no.next())
                                 {center_serial_no=center_name+1;}
                                 else
{
    String received_serial_no=rsserial_no.getString("serial_no");
    center_serial_no=received_serial_no.substring(0, 3);
    String center_serial_no1=received_serial_no.substring(3);
    //int new_serial_no=0;

     int new_serial_no=Integer.parseInt(center_serial_no1);

    new_serial_no=new_serial_no+1;
    center_serial_no=center_serial_no+new_serial_no;}%>
    <input type="hidden" name="srl_no" id="srl_no" value="<%= center_serial_no %>" />
                                <input id="" name="" type="text" value="<%=center_serial_no%>" disabled />


                            </p>
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                            <td>
                            <p>
                                <label for="study_enrolment_no">Study enrolment No</label>
                                <input tabindex="2" id="study_enrolment_no" name="study_enrolment_no" type="text" />
                            </p>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <p>
                                <label for="nm">Name</label>
                                <input tabindex="3" id="nm" name="nm" type="text" />
                            </p>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <p>
                                <label for="age">Age</label>
                                <input tabindex="4" id="age" name="age" type="text"/>
                            </p>
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                            <td>
                            <p>
                                <label for="gender">Gender</label>
                                <!-- <input id="gender" name="gender" type="text" /> -->
                                <select id="gender" name="gender" tabindex="">
                                <option value="Male">Male</option>
                                <option value="Female">Female</option>
                                <option value="Other">Other</option>
                                </select>
                            </p>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <p>
                                <label for="address">Address</label>
                                <input id="address" name="address" type="text" tabindex=""/>
                            </p>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <p>
                                <label for="ph_no">Phone No</label>
                                <input id="ph_no" name="ph_no" type="text" class="nocheck" tabindex=""/>
                            </p>
                            </td>
                            </tr>

                             <tr>
                            <td>
                            <p>
                                <label for="occupation">Occupation</label>
                                <input id="occupation" name="occupation" type="text" tabindex=""/>
                            </p>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <p>
                                <label for="marital_status">Marital status</label>
                                <select id="maritial_status" name="maritial_status" tabindex="">
                                    <option value="">Select</option>
                                    <option value="Yes">Married</option>
                                    <option value="No">Unmarried</option>
                                    </select>
                            </p>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <p>
                                <label for="blood_gr">Blood group</label>
                                <input id="blood_gr" name="blood_gr" type="text" tabindex=""/>
                            </p>
                            </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                            <td>
                            <p>
                                <label for="religion">Religion/Cast/Community</label>
                                <select id="religion" name="religion" class="nocheck" tabindex="">
                                    <option value="">Select</option>
                                    <option value="Hindu">Hindu</option>
                                    <option value="Muslim">Muslim</option>
                                    <option value="Christian">Christian</option>
                                    <option value="Buddhist">Buddhist</option>
                                    <option value="Other">Other</option>
                                </select>
                            </p>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <p>
                                <label for="vac_hbsag">Vaccinated for HBsAg</label>
                                <select id="vac_hbsag" name="vac_hbsag" tabindex="">
                                    <option value="">Select</option>
                                    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                                    <option value="No">No</option>
                                    </select>                               
                            </p>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <p>
                                <label for="monthly_income">Monthly Income</label>
                                <input id="monthly_income" name="monthly_income" type="text" tabindex=""/>
                            </p>
                            </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="3">

                                <p>
                                <label for="edu_level">Education level</label>
                                <select id="edu_level" name="edu_level" tabindex="">
                                    <option value="">Select</option>

                                    <%
                                while(rsLevel.next()){
                                %>

                                <option value="<%= rsLevel.getInt("id") %>"><%= rsLevel.getString("edu_name") %></option>
                                <%
                                }
                                %>

                                </select>
                            </p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            </table>
                        </fieldset>
```

tell me how can i fix this problem. even though i have use `tabindex` but it is not working properly

Comment: Can you [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) this?

Answer (score 0):

Focus the initial element manually

```
document.getElementById("initFocus").focus();
```

and use tabindex, it works good. [See the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/66ES7/). Also [read this](http://drublic.de/blog/accessible-dialogs-modals/)  - some interesting things about playing with tabindexes.

Comment: I am getting the same thing but after adding this line on page load the cursor points to that selected textfiedl and then on clicking tab button it moves on to the next page. then on the next page it navigate to certain fields then without completing it goes on to the next fieldset.

Comment: Yes, it changes the focus goes. Only the js code i posted to set initial focus and check twice tabindex attributes on you fields.

Comment: yes it is working but i want to limit my tabindex to the fieldset in which i am woking . after reaching the last textfield when i press tab it goes to the second fieldset's first tab. how can i overcome this situation